# Failing to save information across tests in Python unit tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to save information from one test to the next in Python, and it is not saved. I understand why really each test should stand alone, and in my case (where I want to create a company and then a bunch of sub-companies) I could figure out how to work around it, but I wanted to understand if there is a simple explanation for why what I am doing is failing and a simple way to do it.

Here is a pretty much minimal reproducible example (I do show trying two approaches, both of which failed, and perhaps putting it in the context of a unit test is irrelevant).

```
"""Jeremy Kahan, July 2021, automated test of self
trying to understand how one might save info from one test to the next
"""
import unittest #pytest might also be an option, for now keeping simple

class TestSelf(unittest.TestCase):
"""Test class to check on communicating between tests with self"""
test2 = -1#thought perhaps class level variable would help
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    """


    Parameters
    ----------
    cls : object of this class
        reference to self.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    print('in setup') # should appear once, and it does
    cls.test1 = -1 #holds the test value



def test_alpha(self):
    """

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    print('in alpha before test1: ' + str(self.test1) + ' test2: ' + str(self.test2))
    self.test1 = 0
    self.test2 = 0
    print('in alpha after test1: ' + str(self.test1) + ' test2: ' + str(self.test2))





def test_beta(self):
    """
    runs after test_alpha, whether because of order in file or alphabetical

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    print('in beta before test1: ' + str(self.test1) + ' test2: ' + str(self.test2))
    self.test1 = 1
    self.test2 = 1
    print('in beta after test1: ' + str(self.test1) + ' test2: ' + str(self.test2))



@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    print('in tear down test1: ' + str(cls.test1) + ' test2: ' + str(cls.test2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #setting variables here made no difference
    unittest.main()
```

output was:

```
..in setup
in alpha before test1: -1 test2: -1
in alpha after test1: 0 test2: 0
in beta before test1: -1 test2: -1
in beta after test1: 1 test2: 1
in tear down test1: -1 test2: -1
```

I was shooting for:

```
in beta before test1: 0 test2: 0
in tear down test1: 1 test2: 1
```

I think there is something fundamental I am missing about `self` in Python. I would welcome an explanation and a way to do what I am trying to do (or a compelling explanation about why I really really should not do it). Thanks in advance.

I suppose the good news here is everything runs once and in the order I expect.

Comment: I was able to work around it in my context, having the 2nd test get the information (not shared by the first test) from what was present on the browser screen. I am not stuck but still curious.

Comment: Writing to a class level variable should be done via `__class__`, e.g. `self.__class__.test = 1`, otherwise you will just create an instance variable of the same name. Using a class level variable should work, if you do it right, instance variables will not work, because a new test instance is created for each test.

Comment: That worked for assigning both test1 and test2. So underscore underscore class underscore underscore is the equivalent of declaring something static to a class in Java?

Comment: Well, no, you usually declare class variables just by writing them in the class scope (e.g. outside the methods), or using the `cls` parameter if in a class method, as you did. `__class__` just provides access to the class object from an instance, and therefore access to the class variables.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your patience. If you want to cut and paste this all and write it up as an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad to help, but I think this is basic Python stuff and is already covered in other questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235109/discussion-between-jeremy-kahan-and-mrbean-bremen).